# Trigger Next Previous click event callback before changed.owl.carousel or translate.owl.carousel

Tags: jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I have an owl carousel on a page.

I need to run some code when the next and prev buttons are clicked before the `changed.owl.carousel` event callback.

```
$("#owl-carousel").on("click", ".owl-prev,.owl-next", function() {
  console.log("slide change is triggered"); 
});

$("#owl-demo").on("changed.owl.carousel", function() {
  console.log("slide has changed"); 
});
```

The problem is that the callback for `changed.owl.carousel` is triggered before the click events on next and prev buttons.

I've looked around and it seems there's no event that triggers on next and prev buttons click.

One potential solution I can think of is to have custom next and prev buttons that manually triggers transition of slides and I can run some code before.

But I'm looking for a different solution that can support my case. Thank you.